# Setting the current time on a buffered source

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

In an html5 element I can set the current time of the audio track by simply changing the value of `audio.currentTime`, but I don't understand how to achieve this using the web audio api and a buffered source. I tried to change `context.currentTime` but it didn't work because it's read only.

How can I set the current time on a buffered source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the current time in a playing buffersource the way you can seek in an  element.  You need to shut down the current node (stop() and disconnect()) and create a new buffersource node that points to the same AudioBuffer, and start it with the appropriate offset.